# how to include groovy dsl script from one groovy file to another

Tags: java, groovy, dsl

I have created a custom dsl command chain using methods in a groovy scripts . I have a problem in accessing this command chain from another groovy file . Is there a way to achieve the functionality ?

I have tried using "evaluate" which is able to load the groovy file , but it is not able to execute the command chain. I have tried using Groovy shell class , but was not able to call the methods.

```
show = { 
        def cube_root= it
}

cube_root = { Math.cbrt(it) }

def please(action) {
    [the: { what ->
        [of: { n ->
            def cube_root=action(what(n))
                println cube_root;
        }]
    }]
}

please show the cube_root of 1000
```

Here I have a CubeRoot.groovy in which executing "please show the cube_root of 1000" produces the result as 10

I have another groovy file called "Main.groovy" . Is there a way to execute the above command chain directly in Main.groovy as "please show the cube_root of 1000" and get the desired output ?

Main.groovy

```
please show the cube_root of 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `include` operation in groovy/java

and you could use **GroovyShell**

if you could represent your "dsl" as closures then for example this should work:

```
//assume you could load the lang definition and expression from files  
def cfg = new ConfigSlurper().parse( '''
    show = { 
            def cube_root= it
    }

    cube_root = { Math.cbrt(it) }

    please = {action->
        [the: { what ->
            [of: { n ->
                def cube_root=action(what(n))
                    println cube_root;
            }]
        }]
    }  
''' )

new GroovyShell(cfg as Binding).evaluate(''' please show the cube_root of 1000 ''')
```

---

another way - use class loader

file **Lang1.groovy**

```
class Lang1{
    static void init(Script s){
        //let init script passed as parameter with variables 
        s.show = { 
           def cube_root= it
        }
        s.cube_root = { Math.cbrt(it) }

        s.please = {action->
            [the: { what ->
                [of: { n ->
                    def cube_root=action(what(n))
                        println cube_root;
                }]
            }]
        }  
    }
}
```

file **Main.groovy**

```
Lang1.init(this)

please show the cube_root of 1000
```

and run from command line: `groovy Main.groovy`

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. Is any way to load the script as give file path only and Binding it instead of load the full script in Main.groovy ?

Comment: `def cfg = new ConfigSlurper().parse( new File(path_to_config).toURI().toURL() )`

Comment: however there are a lot of variants. maybe i just can't understand what do you want..

Comment: What I wanted to do is that , I have various groovy statements similar to "please show the cube_root of 1000" in various groovy file .I want to import all these groovy files into a groovy and  build a new statement using these statements. Is it possible ?

Comment: I've added another case to the answer