# Groovy call another script to set variables

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I'm trying to define variables in another groovy script that I want to use in my current script. I have two scripts like this:

script1.groovy

```
thing = evaluate(new File("script2.groovy"))
thing.setLocalEnv()
println(state)
```

script2.groovy

```
static def setLocalEnv(){
    def state = "hi"
    def item = "hey"
}
```

When I `println(state)`, I get a missing property exception. Basically I want script2 to have config variables that I can load in the context of script1. How can I do this?

Comment: why you need it so complicated? why not to load configuration/properties and work with it?

Comment: Ihmo similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540716/how-to-include-groovy-dsl-script-from-one-groovy-file-to-another/55541990#55541990

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what/how you want to do exactly, but I guess you can achieve your goal using one of the class available in groovy dynamique scripting capabilities: `groovy.lang.Binding` or `GroovyClassLoader` or `GroovyScriptEngine`, here is an example using `GroovyShell` class:

```
abstract class MyScript extends Script {
    String name

    String greet() {
        "Hello, $name!"
    }
}

import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
config.scriptBaseClass = 'MyScript'
def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), config)
def script = shell.parse('greet()')
assert script instanceof MyScript
script.setName('covfefe')
assert script.run() == 'Hello, covfefe!'
```

This is one way to bind a variable to an external script file, more examples from the doc:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html

P.S. Loading external file can be done with `GroovyClassLoader`:

```
def gcl = new GroovyClassLoader()
def clazz2 = gcl.parseClass(new File(file.absolutePath))
```

Hope this helps.